# Swift Pre load view controller before it's shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `viewController` that loads a bunch of pictures into a `scrollView`. It takes a bit of time to load when you first enter so it slows down the UI. I am trying to find the best way to resolve. Maybe I should only load a certain amount of images at a time, but I thought I could just load it before it's shown in the previous view controller.

Here is the function in my `viewController` that takes a long time to load:

```
    func loadImages() {
    var documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    var files: NSArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentPath, error: nil)!

    var currentX: CGFloat = 0.0

    for image in files {
        var im : NSString = image as NSString
        var imagePath = documentPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(im)
        var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        var rect = imageView.frame
        rect.origin.x = currentX
        imageView.frame = rect
        //            imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        imageView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

        currentX += imageView.frame.size.width

        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

//        currentX += UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin
}
```

In my previous view controller I tried just doing:

```
var imageView = ImagesViewController().view
```

But that does not seem to do it. I get: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Is there any way to do it? Or another solution you would recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just use a collection view with cells for the images.

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem not in UI. Where do you call loadImage method? (better not to load images in the main queue) For more quick work with image you can decompress them.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 1), NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I'm calling it in viewDidLoad.. Should I be doing it in a background task?

Comment: It is correct place for change UI. If u have a lot of images that has reason. Why don't you use UICollectionView ?

Answer (score 0):

Call your loadImages() inside init() or whatever custom initializer you're using.